# Why can't I binding a array to a dependencyproperty using c#?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, data-binding, dependency-properties

**What I Do**
create a user control which one of its DependencyProperty binds to a string array

```
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TaskListProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("TaskList",
                                typeof(string[]),
                                typeof(MainControl),
                                null);

    public string TaskList
    {
        get { return (string[])GetValue(TaskListProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TaskListProperty, value); }
    }
```

**What I got**
a error for this code

```
    get { return (string[])GetValue(TaskListProperty); }
```

> > Error:Cannot implicitly convert type 'string[]' to 'string'

**How**
Why does this error happen, don't I register its type of source to string array? How to solve it?

Comment: The type of your property must be `string[]`, not `string`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error message is right. You forgot the `[]` for your property type.

```
public string[] TaskList
{
    get { return (string[])GetValue(TaskListProperty); }
    set { SetValue(TaskListProperty, value); }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As for the error, @Michael and @herzmeister were right, you forgot `[]`. But to avoid a performance warning [CA1819: Properties should not return arrays](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0fss9skc.aspx) I would advice you to change the property to return a collection, if you can do it.